# How to encode hyphen for POST

Tags: python, post

I want to send a POST request to an API.

API parameters

```
api = {
 'url': 'test.com',
 'path': 'myapi.cgi',
 'port': 443,
 'method': 'POST',
 'params': {
   'o': 'my-org',
   'i': '322e9c5eefd1953f788bdefdd7e627d1_bb604d924aefdd7c25b14a382dea3585'
 }
}
```

I send HTTPS request like this:

```
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(self.api['url'], self.api['port'], timeout=5, context=httplib.ssl._create_unverified_context())
conn.request(self.api['method'], self.api['path'], urllib.urlencode(self.api['params']), headers)
```

Here I encode the parameters with `urlencode`.

I get a response from the API: `Invalid chars in organization`.
The call worked when I used an organization name without a hyphen. So, I guess the problem is with `-` char.

How to encode the `my-org` word correctly? Is `-` a legitimate character for the POST request, maybe I don't need to encode it?

I don't have access to the API source code.

Comment: Is it possible that the API simply does not allow this character? Then you have to use a different name, no encoding will help you.

Comment: Try unicode character : U+002D instead of -   . A python source code parsed will \u002D

Comment: @ShekharSamanta do you mean I have to encode my POST string like "i=322e9c5eefd1953f788bdefdd7e627d1_bb604d924aefdd7c25b14a382dea3585&o=myU+002Dorg" ??

Comment: not exactly sure, give it a try : i=322e9c5eefd1953f788bdefdd7e627d1_bb604d924aefdd7c25b14a38‌​2dea3585&o=my\u002Do‌​rg

Comment: @fafl Probably it is. I asked the API developer and now I'm waiting for his response.

Comment: @ShekharSamanta, it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

No need to encode, basically you need to change all the **'** for **"** then add at the start of the payload ''' and at the end.

Example:

```
api = '''{
 "url": "test.com",
 "path": "myapi.cgi",
 "port": 443,
 "method": "POST",
 "params": {
   "o": "my-org",
   "i": "322e9c5eefd1953f788bdefdd7e627d1_bb604d924aefdd7c25b14a382dea3585"
 }
}'''
```

This works with spaces, or special characters.
Regards.